# Does rTMS therapy require medical licensing?

Tags: tms

In my research project, besides sound and light therapies, I would like to experiment with rTMS (repetitive transcranial magnetic stimulation) on volunteers. I wonder if this requires medical licensing?

Comment: Your best bet is to contact your IRB (or its equivalent) for your institution.  They are ultimately going to be the one to make the decision as to whether your research will proceed.

Comment: @ChuckSherrington - That would be the perfect solution but this is private research and I have no IRB. It's just me and some friends.

Comment: If you are going to do human subjects research in *any* context, it needs to be approved by an IRB.  What if someone gets hurt?  The IRB would be the one to determine whether you need a clinician to supervise things.

Comment: It is unethical to do human subjects research of any kind without IRB, including plenty of things much less invasive than TMS. Chuck says "best bet" but I would strongly strengthen that to "only ethical and legal bet"

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the country, but, for most of them (incl. USA and EU), you don't need a medical license to perform biomedical *research*, including human experiments with TMS. However, you will need legal approval, such as certified research environment, ethics/IRB permission, etc. Also, one should delineate research and clinical trials, which are governed by a special set of rules and, most often, require medical environment.